# How to connect to SQL Server provided by AppHarbour

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, appharbor

I am new to AppHarbour and I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application here. I have successfully deployed the web application.

Now I want to run some sql scripts on the database provided.

For which I have followed the following steps...

**Step 1 :**
[image]
**Step 2 :**
[image]
**Step 3 :**
[image]

Now here I get the server name, username and password as well as the database name, but !

When I try connecting to this database using `SQL Server Management Studio` I just cannot connect to it.

I always get the following error message

> > TITLE: Connect to Server
> >     Cannot connect to e2f7c78d*********b9.sqlserver.sequelizer.com.
> >
> > ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> >     This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers. (ConnectionDlg)

Please can some one help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Note: You have hidden your server address on screenshot but in error message it's visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appharbor uses Sql Server 2008 R2 (Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services, version 10.50.1600.1). Use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 version or newer and it should work.

Comment: interesting ! and the hunt for SQL Server Management Studio 2008 begins.. :)

Comment: You can download free 2012 Express version from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062 ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe or ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe